# Where is 'missing value' coming from in this repeat block?

Tags: applescript

I am creating a text file and looping through every Safari window, every tab, and pasting each link into the `.txt` file. However I am getting an extra `missing value` written to the `.txt` file. I know I can explicitly check for missing values but I don't understand where is the "empty" window/value?

```apple
on run {input, parameters}

    (* create text file to hold links *)
    tell application "Finder" to make file at desktop with properties {name:"links_0"}
    set classicPath to (((path to desktop folder) as string) & "links_0")

    (* get links of all windows *)
    tell application "Safari"

        repeat with this_window in windows

            set the_URLs to ""  
            repeat with this_tab in tabs of this_window     
                set the_URLs to the_URLs & URL of this_tab & return     
            end repeat

            do shell script "echo " & quoted form of the_URLs & " >> " & POSIX path of (classicPath)
            do shell script "echo >> " & POSIX path of (classicPath)        
        end repeat
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

sample output (2 windows, each with 2 tabs):

```
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/64896
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/22543

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/25140
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/22546

missing value
```

Comment: What arguments are you calling it with? Are you sure, for example, that input has a value?

Comment: @Lorccan I am not calling it with any parameters and there is no input ... this was the default "skeleton" when I selected 'Run AppleScript' in Automator and I just put all my code in the `on run` block. But if I'm not writing `input` anywhere in the file it shouldn't matter, right? If I take out `{input, parameters}` it still writes `missing value` however.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is an invisible window open? `tell application "Safari` count of windows`.

Comment: When I run the code in Script Editor without `on run ... end run` and deleting the line `return input` I don't get "missing value" written in the file.  What are you doing before and after this in Automator?  I just tried running your script in Automator and I don't get "missing value" written in links_0 either. Perhaps Ted's suggestion of a hidden window is the most likely cause?

Comment: Please have a look at [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html) as it shows what some might consider a more proper form of writing to files using AppleScript without the use of a `do shell script` _command_. It also shows _code_ missing from CJK's answer in which a file should be closed after being written to.  It also wraps relevant code in a `try` _statement_ so if there is an error it attempts to close the file.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be:

```
set my text item delimiters to linefeed
set fp to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) & "links_0.txt"

close access (open for access fp) -- Create the file if it doesn't exist
# set eof of fp to 0 -- Erase any existing contents in the file

tell application id "com.apple.Safari" to tell every tab of every window ¬
        to tell (the URL as text) & linefeed to continue write it to fp ¬
        starting at eof
```

This currently appends URLs to the end of the file.  To overwrite the file, uncomment this line:

```
# set eof of fp to 0
```

by removing the hash symbol.

---

**Note**: There's potential for confusion having read the comment left by @user3439894, where he states:

> *"It also shows code missing from CJK's answer in which a file should be closed after being written to. It also wraps relevant code in a try statement so if there is an error it attempts to close the file."*

I would take what you read at the provided link with a pinch of salt.  Sadly, a lot of the AppleScript documentation from Apple contains code that is poorly written and is part of the reason a lot of bad AppleScript persists so pervasively on the internet.  Some of the documentation provided by Apple is also flat out wrong, which makes it very difficult for people to learn from and to know whose advice to take.

The code I have provided above, I assure you, is very much complete.  Read on for a pretty boring explanation that I wish I didn't have to give, but now have to:

You'll see a lot of people do this:

```
set fh to open for access filepath with write permission
write somedata to fh
close access fh
```

It's not wrong, per se, but it's a pretty draconian way of using these read/write commands, which persists among many simply because they've always done it that way, and only seen it done that way.  It's cumbersome and completely unnecessary<sup>1</sup>.

@user3439894 alluded to a `try` statement, which would, indeed, be needed for this method.  `open for access` opens a file handle that was necessary in order to write out to a file.  However, if an error in the script occurs during the write process, then the file handle is left dangling because the script terminates before being able to `close access` to the file.  The way around this would be to use a `try` statement whose purpose was to catch an error, and ensure the `close access` command still gets executed:

```
try
        set fh to open for access filepath with write permission
        write somedata to fh
        close access fh
on error
        close access fh
end try
```

`open for access` and `close access` are redundant.  There's no need to use them, and in fact, their use is only creating a potential problem that then needs a workaround in order to solve.

`write`--and `read`--are safe and advisable to use on their own, and they don't need a `try` block to catch potential errors.  So why do the two commands I just called *redundant* appear in my script at all ?

```
close access (open for access fp)
```

One nifty side effect of the `open for access` command is that it will create a file at the specified path if one doesn't already exist.  This is really useful because it negates the need to call out to *System Events* or (shudder) *Finder* to do this for you.  It also has seems to have a wider scope for creating files at locations that other AppleScript applications don't have permission to access if they're sandboxed, etc.

Once `open for access` has created the file--or opened one that already exists--it returns a reference to the file handle.  Then `close access` is used to immediately destroy file handle, because we don't actually have any use for it, but also don't want it left open.  There's also no need for a `try` block: any error that could possibly arise would do so during the creation of the file handle, which would mean that the file handle won't be created, and so cannot be left open.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>The way the data gets written out now is fundamentally different to how it was written out when these commands were first introduced, and previously, `write` would not be able to access a file without first explicitly opening a file handle to it and declaring the need for writing permissions.  Now, everything gets handled within the `write` command itself, including clean up.</sub>

Comment: If I'm understanding what you wrote correctly, `write` closes the _file handle_ without the need to explicitly `close` it, and if there isn't enough space for what I'm writing, I do not need any _error handling_? Wow, that good to know!

Comment: You will still get an error generated from running out of disk space, but you shouldn't be left with an open file handle.

Comment: I remember back in the day where good coding practices first involved calculating whether of not the destination had ample space to make the write, as disks were very small back in those days, and file handles always had to be explicitly closed too. Moving forwards I remember when even with **AppleScript** one had to explicitly close the file handle, although I do not know when that changed, I do remember having issue if it wasn't. It's not that I do no believe you; however, when I get the time I'll have to do some testing to see if explicitly closing the file handle is no longer necessary.

Comment: That said, IMO good coding practices always includes proper error handling when making disk writes, and anything else that can be problematic. This is in part why I typically post the note that I do about error handling at the bottom of any post that includes coding.

Comment: I agree with you in general about error handling, but I think this is a complex topic. I think it's good that you're conscientious about adding a footnote to remind users to have this mind, but almost all of the AppleScript questions that are posted are from novices that will either not know anything about error handling, or those that consider wrapping everything in a `try` block to be "error handling", but often creates more problems in AS yet is something that perseveres in scripts of seasoned coders. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Con'td_ Error handling doesn't really exist in the same way as, say, C, and I personally feel the `try` statement ought not to exist in AppleScript at all, and is the antithesis to good coding practice.  But it's a convenience feature that lets one bypass more rigorous checks that would make a script unseemly.  I suppose this is the difference between programming and scripting: as you say, from a programmer's perspective, one would check disk space, allocate memory resources, and periodically assess progress during the write out process. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _Cont'd..._ But much of AS is just a wrapper for ObjC methods, like the `write` command, which is meant to ease the burden of doing this.  But I also know that the way data is written to the filesystem nowadays--at least since I was at university--has evolved, and there seems to be so many techniques that I have to admit escape my comprehension.  But my understanding is that the `write` command uses an atomic process, which, if interrupted, won't corrupt data or leave open handles, but is likely slower than previously (meaning the one benefit to explicitly opening a handle is improved speed).